# Simple Twitter client to post all text entry

Tags: scripts

This is a bit of a weird question, and I don't even know if it belongs here or not.

I want to set up a Ubuntu box with a keyboard and a twitter program, so that everything that is typed into the keyboard is posted on twitter. So what I am looking for is a simple twitter client that will force all input via keyboard into a tweet and post to twitter after 140 chars, after the enter key, and/or a time period.

Basically what I am planning is a little experiment to leave a keyboard somewhere it can be typed on and played with, and post all text entry through to twitter automatically.

The alternative is to simply save all entered text to a file, but I would prefer the twitter approach.

Does anyone have any ideas if there is a program/script out there that will do this for me?

I am mainly looking for a command line script, as GUI programs are easier to exit or lose focus than a command line.

Comment: If you don't get anything here, and if you have some programming experience, you could head over to Stack Overflow to get some ideas on how to write the program yourself. I don't think it'd be that hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure all of this can be done through a simple python script. Interesting idea. I am sure you have some use for it.

I would recommend taking a look at the [twitter-python API](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/) -- simple and straightforward and it would be easy integrate your recording keystroke requirement as well.

If you need help making things work or have questions. stackoverflow.com is an amazing resource.

Comment: This would be ridiculously simple to do in Python. ~3 hours for a complete novice, 20 minutes for a pro.

Answer (score 0):

There are some command-line twitter clients (either [hand](http://www.ubuntu-unleashed.com/2008/03/howto-twitter-from-command-line-in.html) [rolled](http://www.fsckin.com/2008/03/19/twittering-from-the-command-line/), or [purpose built](http://wiki.github.com/jgoerzen/twidge/)), but it sounds like you have a pretty specific set of features in mind.

I think you'll have to add a bunch of scripts around an existing client.

Good luck. =)